# how to force context switching in embedded development kit

Tags: multithreading, embedded, multiprocessing, context-switch

i learn these days about embedded development with multi processors, and i wanted to ask if it is possible to force a context switching in debug mode, to access a specific thread i want?.
and if it is possible, is there a way to do this through the debugger? 
the debugger i use is gdb to debug the system.

i have read posts that were posted here, but non really assisted me about these questions.

p.s, i know it is probably not safe action, but it is necessary for me.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Some commercial development systems for embedded systems have native thread debugging, for a number of popular embedded operating systems, e.g. you get a list of running threads and you can pick the one you would like to debug.

Comment: can i switch to other thread, while i am already in debug mode of other thread?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to freely switch between threads. Of course, it depends on the tools you are using, which in turn depend on the processor that is used.

Comment: You cannot normally force a thread to run - it runs when it is scheduled.  In a pre-emptive priority based RTOS scheduler it makes little sense. In a GPOS and an application with multiple non-blocking/yielding threads relying only on time-slicing for scheduling it is conceivable, but that is a very specific scenario.

Comment: ok, thanks, do you know of a way to context switch for example with the gdb debugger?

Comment: `thread` *<threadno>* as described [here](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Threads.html) - the GDB manual; who'd have thought! ;-)  However whether it is supported in any particular gdb build will depend target it was built for.  The link discusses other thread debugging features such as thread specific break-points.

Answer (score 2):

Whether this was possible or desirable would probably depend on the nature of your operating system and application.  In a typical RTOS based application such action would generally be inappropriate.  Normally in an RTOS a thread waits on some event using some blocking function.  To switch to that thread would require "unblocking" when the expected even has not occurred, so the subsequent processing is likely to fail.

Most blocking functions in an RTOS have an option for a timeout that would cause the function to return without the event occurring.  Setting a breakpoint after the function the thread is blocked on and either waiting for the timeout or the event will allow you to start stepping the thread.

Comment: i kind of lost you, do you mean to put breakpoint at the start of a function of other thread, and that way i will be on other thread?

Comment: @user1765376: No what I am suggesting is that what you are asking for cannot in the general case be done. Instead, in a typical real-time embedded design most threads comprise a non-terminating loop blocking at a single point awaiting an event. Place a break-point immediately *after* the blocking function, and will be hit when the thread is scheduled normally. If you have multiple threads instantiated on a single function, you will need an OS that supports thread-specific breakpoints (like VxWorks); for most simple systems the breakpoint will be hit when *any* of the threads are scheduled.